# change the serialized data

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I know question title is not clear and sorry for that.

my question is how can I change the way response looks right now

```
# serializers.py
class UserCommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    slug = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
       model = Comment
       fields = '__all__'

    def get_slug(self, obj):
       id = obj.object_id
       return BlogPost.objects.values('slug').get(id=id)
```

The response looks something like this

```
"results": [
    {
        "id": 49,
        "slug": {
            "slug": "ghfj-jkbkj-kjkjk"
        },
    }]
```

I want it to look

```
"results": [
    {
        "id": 49,
        "slug": "ghfj-jkbkj-kjkjk"
    }]
```

See, if you can help

Comment: Can you please clear why put  extra `},` in required snippet?

Comment: edited the question

Comment: Can you give a try removing  `slug = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)` and  whole `get_slug` function. Keep just `Meta` class

Comment: well , I tried that too, then there will be no slug field in the response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return the slug and not the blog post from the serializer method field:

```
def get_slug(self, obj):
       id = obj.object_id
       return BlogPost.objects.values('slug').get(id=id)['slug']
```

Comment: it gives `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'slug'`

Comment: Yes, I forgot you were using values instead of getting the entire object. I'll update

Comment: Thank you I got this idea because of you

Answer (score 1):

Ok, for now I solved it with these changes

```
class UserCommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    slug = serializers.SerializerMethodField(
        read_only=True)

    class Meta:
       model = Comment
       fields = '__all__'

    def get_slug(self, obj):
        id = obj.object_id
        blog = BlogPost.objects.values('slug').get(id=id)
        return blog['slug']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use:

```
class UserCommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    slug = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
       model = Comment
       fields = '__all__'

    def get_slug(self, obj):
       id = obj.object_id
       return BlogPost.objects.get(id=id).slug
```

if relation to `BlogPost` from `Comment` is ForeignKey, then simply use:

```
class UserCommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    slug = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
       model = Comment
       fields = '__all__'

    def get_slug(self, obj):
       return obj.object.slug
```

Even better solution:

```
class UserCommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    slug = serializers.SlugField(read_only=True, source='object.slug')
```

Here is the documentation related to [source](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source).